# Engineering change orders (ECOs) and software version control

Tags: version-control, versioning, software, engineering, software-updates

Is it common practice in the software development/engineering profession for engineering change orders (ECOs) to be used for or in conjunction with software version control? Is this a good idea? Are there any pros or cons?

Comment: For a software-only product (or change), I don't see an advantage of having an ECO in addition to software version control, but it can be useful if you add non-software components in the mix.

Comment: Do you mean by "ECO" what most of the software engineering world calls a "change request"? Please clarify.

Comment: No, by "ECO" I mean solely as it is used by, say, the electrical engineering world.

Comment: @reformed: then please enlighten software engineers like me who are not educated in electrical engineering terms what that you mean by ECO and how it is different from a change request.

Comment: @DocBrown Software engineers who are not familiar with ECOs will not be able to answer whether or not it is common practice to use them, and this lack of knowledge may in itself suggest in answer to my question that this is not common practice.

Comment: @reformed: maybe SEs just use just a different term for it? From the Wikipedia article about [ECO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_change_order) it appears to me an ECO does not really differ from a formal [change request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_request), and change requests are often (but not always) used in conjunction with source control.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the reference. I agree, that it looks like ECOs are similar enough to change requests that they could be synonymous. In that case then this answers my question in the affirmative.

Comment: Define "In conjunction".

Comment: @whatsisname Software version control is used as would be normally. ECOs required/issued for substantive software changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK what you call "ECO" in electrical engineering is called a ["change request"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_request) in software development. Many development teams use issue or bug tracking systems to manage their change requests in form of "tickets", and I am pretty sure a certain percentage of those teams add the issue ID, or bug ID, or ticket number, to the commit messages when committing to version control (see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/121584/9113) for example). There are even some bug trackers with version control integration (see [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682740/best-solution-for-integrated-bug-tracking-wiki-and-version-control)), or fully integrated products like Microsoft's TFS.

So the answer to your question *"is it common practice"* is, yes, to some degree. Not 100% popular, not necessary for everyone or every team, but some find it helpful and use it.

Comment: Some companies provide multiple development products and have some fun integrations.  I'll use Jira and BitBucket as an example.  If you link the two and have the Jira Story Number (XXX-123) in your commit message, when your viewing the Jira Story there is a section where it links directly to the commit.  One of the reasons it became mandatory on my team.